# Spring Boot and Jackson, JSR310 in response body

Tags: spring-boot

The JacksonAutoConfiguration initializes an ObjectMapper with the JSR310Module registered. Then HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration initializes a MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter. But this MessageConverter never gets plugged in the RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.

As a result:

- If the controller returns a object which should be jsonified by Jackson, dates are poorly converted because the wrong MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter is used (initialized in WebMvcConfigurationSupport#addDefaultHttpMessageConverters)
- But, if the ObjectMapper is injected in the controller and used to jsonify the same object, then the date format is alright.

How can I can wake the WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter up? What should I do to bind the configured Jackson ObjectMapper with Spring MVC and make it handle response bodies?

Comment: Did you switch off the Spring Boot web configuration? If you use `@EnableWebMvc` that would explain your symptoms.

Comment: That's it. So the rule thumb is: do not use @EnableWebMvc with Spring Boot, unless you wan't to customize Web MVC configuration?

Comment: Yes, that's a good rule of thumb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `@EnableWebMvc` that would explain your symptoms So the rule thumb is: do not use `@EnableWebMvc` with Spring Boot, unless you wan't to customize Web MVC configuration?