# Spring web: @RequestBody Json conversion for Java8 LocalTime not working

Tags: json, spring-mvc, java-8, spring-boot, java-time

In my Spring REST webapp, I'm trying to get a controller working with Java8 LocalTime.
I'm sending this Json in a POST request

```
{
    "hour": "0",
    "minute": "0",
    "second": "0",
    "nano": "0"
}
```

and I get a `HttpMessageNotReadableException` with the following Jackson error

```
Could not read JSON: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class java.time.LocalTime]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?) 
at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@58cfa2a0; line: 2, column: 5]; 
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class java.time.LocalTime]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?) 
at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@58cfa2a0; line: 2, column: 5]
```

I'm using spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE with spring-boot-starter-web-1.0.2.RELEASE, jackson-databind-2.4.2 and jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.4.2

From what I understood googling around, Spring should automatically register JSR-310 modules for Java8.time objects.

I found an answer to my problem, but it does not work for me: [Spring Boot and Jackson, JSR310 in response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329875/spring-boot-and-jackson-jsr310-in-response-body)

I have no configurations annotated with @EnableWebMvc and here is my only configuration class

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy()
@Configuration
@ImportResource(value = "Beans.xml") 
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new StringToLocalDateTime());
        registry.addConverter(new LocalDateTimeToString());
        registry.addConverter(new StringToLocalDate());
        registry.addConverter(new LocalDateToString());
        registry.addConverter(new StringToLocalTime());
        registry.addConverter(new LocalTimeToString());
    }
}
```

Can you suggest what's wrong in my configuration?

Comment: People have taken the time to help you and answer. Please take the time to accept an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your configuration.

I suggest you to update Spring Boot to 1.2.0.RELEASE. It uses Spring 4.1.3 packages, which have resolved issue with `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`. To get more info read: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1620#issuecomment-58016018 . It worked in my case.

If you do not want to update Spring Boot version, probably the least you can do is to annotate `LocalTime`'s fields explicitly like that:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = DateTimeSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = DateTimeDeserializer.class)
private LocalTime date;
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to register the module as a Bean for the Spring to see it and set it

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JSR310Module jsr310Module() {
        return new JSR310Module();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using SpringBoot simply adding the jar to the classpath (via Maven or Gradle) will suffice. SpringBoot will see it in the classpath and automatically use it.

Answer (score 1):

With SpringBoot 1.5, I used the following dependency and works out of the box!

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```